# Why Spring Boot not using custom ObjectMapper bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have custom ObjectMapper bean annotated as @Primary.

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
        objectMapper.enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS);
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT);
        return objectMapper;
    }

}
```

However when I try to parse form with not same case written enum it gives me error.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/game")
public class GameController {

    private final GameService gameService;

    public GameController(GameService gameService) {
        this.gameService = gameService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createGame(
            @AuthenticationPrincipal String id,
            GameParametersForm gameParametersForm
    ) {
        Result<String> result = gameService.createWebGameSession(id, gameParametersForm);
        return result.toResponseEntity();
    }

}
```

```
public class GameParametersForm {

    private Mode mode;

    public GameParametersForm(
            Mode mode
    ) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    public Mode getMode() {
        return mode;
    }

}
```

Here is build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.12.2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.12.2'
    implementation 'javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I have tried to declare Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder bean. It didn't help. 
Any idea what might be happening, or where else I should be looking to track down the issue?

Comment: PLease add your json payload

Comment: @VovaBilyachat How can I do this? It's form from web page. The problem is when I send same enum in right case it donesn't give me a error.

Comment: You don't need to redefine bean, just edit `application.properties` to enable desired features. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonProperties.java#L44

Comment: @andreoss ```spring.jackson.mapper.accept-case-insensitive-enums=true``` property also not give any result

Comment: So I check the problem mb in jackson. Because after I added feature only in ```application.properties``` without adding ObjectMapper bean. And loggin enabled mapper features of autowired ObjectMapper the feaure is enabled but there is still same problem.

Comment: Tried to parse json data instead of data from form and it worked. Seems some features work only in json.

Answer (score 4):

Check that your letting spring boot auto configure your application.  Less is more in your spring boot application configuration.  If you have added @EnableWebMvc you prevent spring boot from auto configuring your serialization and deserialization.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration

Comment: I have no @EnableWebMvc annotation in any configuration.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` bean, eg. [hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample DemoApplication.java#L152](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/boot/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java#L152)

   ```java
   @Bean
   public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
       return builder -> {
           builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
           builder.featuresToDisable(
                   SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS,
                   SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS,
                   DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES,
                   DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
           builder.featuresToEnable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
       };
   }
   ```
2. Or customize it in spring boot application properties. eg. [hantsy/spring-webmvc-jwt-sample application.yml#L4](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-webmvc-jwt-sample/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml#L4)

   ```yaml
    spring:
      jackson:
        mapper:
          DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION: true
        serialization:
          indent_output: true
          WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS: false
        deserialization:
          FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES: false
          FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES: false
          ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY: true
        default-property-inclusion: non_empty
   ```

Comment: @north32 Remove your Jackson deps please, the web starter will include them. And there are some breaking changes in Jackson 2.12 API. I think Spring Boot 2.4.x will keep with 2.11.x

Comment: not working. I found solution in using json data + @RequestBody

Comment: @north32 Your problem is not related to Jackson at all.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like @north32's problem was not actually related to Thymeleaf. But for those whose problem is related to Thymeleaf I have some info on this. You'll know if your problem is related to Thymeleaf if you're having problems only with serialization and only when actually building a Thymeleaf page and returning that to the frontend.

I ran into this problem when attempting to add support for serialization of HibernateProxy objects using the jackson.datatype.Hibernate5Module. I should have been able to declare this as a @Bean on some @Configuration, then Jackson's AutoConfiguration would have picked this up. But I discovered that Thymeleaf itself instantiates it's own JacksonObjectMapper when it serializes. It does this at org.thymeleaf.standard.serializer.StandardJavaScriptSerializer.JacksonStandardJavaScriptSerializer.

This is honestly absurd. The Thymeleaf library that's used in conjunction with Spring should be attempting to find a bean of ObjectMapper, and using that one, instead of instantiating its own.

I have not found a solution to this yet. I maybe be SOL.

I created an issue for this on the thymeleaf-spring repo. https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring/issues/311